# addrinfo struct not retaining values after function call

Tags: c, sockets, memory

I have a static addrinfo struct being used to save the results of my call to getaddressinfo() within the static function init_socket(). Inside the init_socket() the addrinfo struct has the correct values, but on return it gets zeroed.

Code below of what I am trying to accomplish.

```
static struct addrinfo rxRes;

static int init_socket(struct addrinfo *resInfo, char *host, char *port) {
    struct addrinfo hints;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);

    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;

    if (!host) { // automatically assign ip to result ip of current machine
        hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
    }

    int res = getaddrinfo(host, port, &hints, &resInfo);
    if (res != 0 || !resInfo) {
        PRINT_NET_ERR(res);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("init addrlen: %d\n", resInfo->ai_addrlen); // correct output

    return socket(resInfo->ai_family, resInfo->ai_socktype, resInfo->ai_protocol);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* initialize socket connections */
    int rxsFD = init_socket(&rxRes, TEST_HOST, TEST_PORT);
    printf("main addrlen: %d\n, rxRes.ai_addrlen) // outputs 0
    ...
}
```

Comment: @500-InternalServerError That wouldn't work. The last arg to `getaddrinfo` needs to be a double pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resInfo` is a local variable in the function so any changes to it will not be reflected in the caller. The caller needs to pass in a pointer to a pointer and not just a pointer. The `getaddinfo` will allocate dynamic memory. Yes, it is a little confusing so please see the following corrected code which hopefully makes it clearer.

```
static int init_socket(struct addrinfo **resInfo, char *host, char *port) {
    ..   
    int res = getaddrinfo(host, port, &hints, resInfo);
    ..
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct addrinfo *rxRes;
    /* initialize socket connections */
    int rxsFD = init_socket(&rxRes, TEST_HOST, TEST_PORT);
    printf("main addrlen: %d\n, rxRes->ai_addrlen);

    /* free the result when no longer needed */
    freeaddrinfo(rxRes);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I try to dereference within init_socket and get a segfault  ```printf("init addrlen: %d\n", (*resInfo)->ai_addrlen);```

Comment: Did you copy my original code exactly? Sorry, there was one error. Last arg passed to `getaddrinfo` should be `resInfo` and not `&resInfo`. Answer corrected now.

Comment: Works! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Complementing the answer:

I think you will need to use another pointer to access the `addrinfo struct` inside the function `init_socket()` for the purpose of the `return` using the `socket()` function.

So you can do it:

```
    struct addrinfo *addrRet = *resInfo;
    printf("initsocket: %d\n", addrRet->ai_addrlen);

    return socket(addrRet->ai_family, addrRet->ai_socktype, addrRet->ai_protocol);
```

Sorry by the answer. I can't write a comment (no reputation).

Comment: Yup, I simply did *(addrRet)->ai_family to accomplish this

Comment: Ok. Thank you for sharing this solution. I have tried this in Dev Cpp, but it did returned an error at the compilation time, so I have alternate to that code.